# Do we have any option of adding suppliers and suppliers information in the magento admin?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm new to magento. I need to add suppliers along with our products and the supplier information should also be editable. Please suggest me how can i do this. I'm using Magento 1.7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need an extension for that, no way to do this out of the box :)

Answer (score 1):

You will  need to install an extension for that. I search for some and I just found this: [Suppliers on Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/216965/)

You will have to send him a private message to know it ^^

Answer (score 1):

By default magento not provide this functionality, but still you can do this using magento attribute.

Create one attribute "supplier or something" and assigned this newly created attribute to Attribute Set of magento, now this newly created attribute is display in your product edit page.

If you are neu to magento this link might be useful to you [How to create attribute?](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields)